# Warning: Wrong parameter count for assert()

Tags: php, assert

This is my code for assertion.My php version is 5.2.9 & I am getting correct count($this->states).

```
 $this->states = $this->database->get_multiple_rows("select STATUS_CODES_CODE, STATUS, BEHAVIOR, PREVIOUS
        FROM EXP_STATUS_CODES
        WHERE SOURCE = 'shipment'
        ORDER BY STATUS_CODES_CODE ASC");

 assert( count($this->states)." > 0", "Unable to load states for shipments" );
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this warning of wrong parameter.

Comment: [The FM](http://php.net/assert) states that the second parameter was added in 5.4.8...

Comment: If you're making the assertion a stringthy expression anyway, then use `assert(' count($x)>2  # Bla bla.. ');` right away.